# Regarding projects and experience

Tags: projects

> "I would like to work on an XYZ fantastic project I have in my mind in
>   ABC programming language, but I do not feel that I have the knowledge required or that I
>   am anywhere near experienced enough to perform."

Do you think someone should work on a project (even if it is a small, personal one) and try to acquire skills and knowledge in the process, or he should not even start working on a project unless he has at least a respectable level of experience and knowledge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one is born with every thing. Whatever we learn is through our experience. If you keep on thinking that "i cannot do it", well, then you will never do it. If you have stackoverflow , google and confidence in yourself, go ahead. You can get help on anything from here. You will only learn something when you do a real project. Make mistakes and learn from them.

Comment: Infact i am a software engineer. I started my career 3 months ago. I did not know even the basics of objective c when i joined my company. After training(practically it was a self study) I was put into a live project. The same question was in my mind when my pm allocated me to tthe project, and guess what, I have successfully completed the project. Stop dreaming and start believing.